# slick carousel 1.4 adaptive height and goto

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Slick Carousel 1.4.1 (https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) for different sliders on my page (http://www.branders-development.ch/treuco/index_org.php). If you click on the Navigation you'll scroll to the section mentioned and go to the slide inside the carousel. This works, but if you click to the next-button, the hole carousel crashed.

Slick-Code: 
     $('.clk').click(function(e){

```
    var slideshow   = $(this).attr('owl');
    var slide       = $(this).attr('slide');

    if (typeof slide !== typeof undefined && slide !== false) {

        $( '#' + slideshow ).slick( 'unslick' );

        $('#'+ slideshow).slick({
          infinite: true,
          speed: 1000,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          adaptiveHeight: true,
          initialSlide: slide
        });
    }
});
```

HTML-Navigation:

```
<li class="first"><a slide="1" owl="sl22" rel="sl22#2" class="clk">Vermögensverwaltung</a></li>
```

thanks for help
thomas